# Override default ClickOnce splash screen with a custom one

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clickonce

I have a C# application that uses the ClickOnce distribution method.  ClickOnce automatically checks for a new versions, and if it is available, downloads and installs it on the customer's machine.

My own application has a slash screen, this results in there being two different "splash" screens seen by the user (click once auto-update, and my splash screen).

Is there a way I can override the default ClickOnce auto update screen with my custom splash screen?

Comment: More details please. You're posing the question as if we were familiar with your design and code.

Comment: Thanks for updating my question. I referred to this thread for the splash screen which it works great for me. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/prettygoodsplashscreen.aspx.

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/8d9faf75-c7f0-4d63-a89b-1d30192fab18/

Comment: Links with no context are unhelpful